# How to get data returned from Cloud Functions on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to authenticate an user with a custom token using cloud functions. The code for the token generation is:

```
export const test = functions.https.onCall(() => {
     const uid = 'test_uid'
     admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
     .then((customtoken) => {
         console.log(customtoken)
         return customtoken
     }).catch((error) => {
         console.log(error)
     })
 })
```

The code on the client side is:

```
private void getmessage() {
        FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
                .getHttpsCallable("test")
                .call()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<HttpsCallableResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getResult().getData().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Task is NOT Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

    }
```

The token is successfully logged in the console, but returns null value on the client side. Is there something which I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A callable function needs to return a promise that resolves when the async work is complete.  That promise should resolve with the data to send to the client.  Right now, your function is returning nothing.

Try this instead:

```
return admin.auth()
    .createCustomToken(...)
    .then(...)
    .catch(...)
```